# JS Slider extension/option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Slideshow. I will like to changed it up a bit.

Basically the slider have a click through functionality using `LI`s menu which works good.

But I wanted the option of one Arrow that will loop through the slideshow instead of clicking 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

Just wanted one click that says NEXT and it will do the same thing like the current sliding.

MY FIDDLE is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/myislandshop/67fs2/5/

if this can be done with little change in the JS that will be cool.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a counter of the position instead of retrieving it from the `a`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Utv9w/1/

Comment: Hey Den, How will i extend this so every time it loads in or a click through is carried out, the Slides will be random?